# How to select tr sibling and input on table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I try select and get price after select product and return price on the respect input sibling tr.

I try

```
function getPrice() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val($(this).val());
};
```

and variations with `nth-child()` but I can not.

I need update price value

```
<!-- Django template tags -->
{% for item in items %}
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="product" class="form-control" onchange="getPrice()">
      <!-- Django template tags -->
      {% for product in products %}
        <option value="{{product.pk}}">{{ product.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="price" class="form-control price" type="number" step="0.01">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="quantity" class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="span-is-link no" onclick="removeRow()">
      <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  function getPrice() {
    // Initial test with get value of select.
    // jQuery
    // inpuy in equivalent line of tr
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val($(this).val());
  }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getPrice()` function is not working because as you're calling it through the `onchange` HTML attribute, the `this` keyword will be `window`, that is, the browser global object, not your `<select>` element.

A solution could be replacing `getPrice()` in your HTML `onchange` attribute with `getPrice.call(this)`. That way, `this` inside your function will be the `<select>`.

```
<select name="product" class="form-control" onchange="getPrice.call(this)">
```